# Join query is fast on 1st setup, but much slower on the other

Tags: sql, postgresql, ovh

We have two Postgres setups. The first one (v11) is on AWS RDS, the second one (v12) is on OVH CloudDB. Both contain the exact same indexes and tables. Both have 1GB of RAM and 1 vCPU.

When executing this query:

```
EXPLAIN (
analyze on,
buffers on,
verbose on) 
SELECT
   "User"."id",
   "User"."firstName",
   "User"."lastName",
   "User"."phone",
   "User"."biography",
   "User"."email",
   COUNT("skills"."id") AS "skillsCount",
   COUNT("languagesList"."id") AS "languagesCount",
   COUNT("certificates"."id") AS "certificatesCount",
   COUNT("mobility"."id") AS "mobilityCount",
   COUNT("studies"."id") AS "studiesCount",
   COUNT("experience"."id") AS "experienceCount",
   COUNT("address"."id") AS "addressCount",
   COUNT (DISTINCT "chatMessages".id) AS "chatMessagesCount",
   json_agg(
   CASE
      WHEN
         appointments.id IS NULL 
      THEN
         NULL 
      ELSE
         json_build_object('id', appointments.id, 'validations', json_build_array(json_build_object('managerId', "appointments -> validations"."managerId", 'validated', "appointments -> validations".validated)), 'recruiterUser', json_build_object('id', "appointments -> recruiterUser".id, 'firstName', "appointments -> recruiterUser"."firstName", 'lastName', "appointments -> recruiterUser"."lastName", 'company', json_build_object('id', "appointments -> recruiterUser -> company".id, 'title', "appointments -> recruiterUser -> company".title)), 'day', appointments.day, 'time', appointments.time, 'status', appointments.status) 
   END
) AS "meetings", json_agg(
   CASE
      WHEN
         applications.id IS NULL 
      THEN
         NULL 
      ELSE
         json_build_object('id', applications.id, 'job', json_build_object('id', "applications -> job".id, 'title', "applications -> job".title), 'validations', json_build_array(json_build_object('managerId', "applications -> validations"."managerId", 'validated', "applications -> validations".validated)), 'cv', json_build_object('id', "applications -> cv".id, 'cvFile', "applications -> cv"."cvFile")) 
   END
) AS "Applications", json_agg(
   CASE
      WHEN
         visits.id IS NULL 
      THEN
         NULL 
      ELSE
         json_build_object('id', visits.id, 'time', visits.time, 'jobBoard', json_build_object('anonymized', "visits -> jobBoard".anonymized, 'subdomain', "visits -> jobBoard".subdomain)) 
   END
) AS "Visits", "validations"."id" AS "validations.id", "validations"."validated" AS "validations.validated", "validations"."jobBoardId" AS "validations.jobBoardId" 
FROM
   "Users" AS "User" 
   INNER JOIN
      "UserVisits" AS "visits" 
      ON "User"."id" = "visits"."userId" 
   INNER JOIN
      "JobBoards" AS "visits -> jobBoard" 
      ON "visits"."jobBoardId" = "visits -> jobBoard"."id" 
      AND "visits -> jobBoard"."creator" = 769 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      (
         "JobApplications" AS "applications" 
         INNER JOIN
            "Jobs" AS "applications -> job" 
            ON "applications"."jobId" = "applications -> job"."id" 
         LEFT OUTER JOIN
            "UsersCV" AS "applications -> cv" 
            ON "applications"."cvId" = "applications -> cv"."id" 
         LEFT OUTER JOIN
            "JobApplicationsValidations" AS "applications -> validations" 
            ON "applications"."id" = "applications -> validations"."applicationId" 
      )
      ON "User"."id" = "applications"."userId" 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      (
         "Appointments" AS "appointments" 
         INNER JOIN
            "Users" AS "appointments -> recruiterUser" 
            ON "appointments"."recruiter" = "appointments -> recruiterUser"."id" 
         INNER JOIN
            "Companies" AS "appointments -> recruiterUser -> company" 
            ON "appointments -> recruiterUser"."companyId" = "appointments -> recruiterUser -> company"."id" 
         LEFT OUTER JOIN
            "AppointmentsValidations" AS "appointments -> validations" 
            ON "appointments"."id" = "appointments -> validations"."appointmentId" 
      )
      ON "User"."id" = "appointments"."candidate" 
      AND "appointments"."type" = 'meeting' 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      "ChatMessages" AS "chatMessages" 
      ON "User"."id" = "chatMessages"."userId" 
      AND NOT ("chatMessages"."userId" = 769) 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      "CandidateSkills" AS "skills" 
      ON "User"."id" = "skills"."userId" 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      "CandidateLanguage" AS "languagesList" 
      ON "User"."id" = "languagesList"."userId" 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      "CandidateCertificates" AS "certificates" 
      ON "User"."id" = "certificates"."userId" 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      "CandidateMobility" AS "mobility" 
      ON "User"."id" = "mobility"."userId" 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      "CandidateDiplomas" AS "studies" 
      ON "User"."id" = "studies"."userId" 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      "CandidateExperience" AS "experience" 
      ON "User"."id" = "experience"."userId" 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      "Address" AS "address" 
      ON "User"."id" = "address"."userId" 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      "UserValidations" AS "validations" 
      ON "User"."id" = "validations"."userId" 
      AND "validations"."managerId" = 769 
WHERE
   "User"."roleId" = ANY ('{5}') 
GROUP BY
   "User"."id", "visits"."time", "validations"."id" 
ORDER BY
   "User"."lastName" ASC LIMIT 50 OFFSET '0';
```

The query takes up about 730ms on our AWS setup (which is fine for what we're trying to accomplish). However, when ran on OVH, it takes up about 3500ms.. way too slow!

Here are the EXPLAIN results for both queries:

[AWS](https://paste.c-net.org/PresentReese)
[OVH](https://paste.c-net.org/NewlywedMcqueen)

What could possibly cause this? Is this a ressources problem or one with my code?

Comment: The plans seem to be different. Perhaps the statistics on the OVH database are off? Try running an ANALYZE and see if that helps postgres choose the better plan.

Comment: @BlueStar I ran ANALYZE queries on all the relevant tables and only gained ~80ms.

Comment: if you strip out all the json_agg columns and retry in both environs is there any improvement? are they more similar in performance?  (basically by cutting out features of your query can help identify performance bottlenecks)

Comment: @PaulMaxwell Removing the json_agg columns does improve performance. AWS goes down to 141ms and OVH goes down to 550ms.

Comment: mmm, still a gap in performance - perhaps also remove the order by and re-look  at the explains with these simplifications. is there some major difference in those explains? e.g.addiional i/o or scanning or both... Basically I'm tyring to suggest a "salami" approach, keep cutting back  till you get similar results, then start building back up again which should help identify the problem(s). To be fair I doubt I can really offer much more than this generic type of advice so how much you listen to me is up to you.

Comment: btw: expecting us to read and understand those quite hefty explains isn't something many of us can do or are willing to do. The simpler they are the better it will be to get assistance.

Comment: To make the results van EXPLAIN readable and understandable, you could use https://explain.depesz.com

Comment: Those sure don't look like the same data.  The slow one is aggregating 140,466 rows, the fast one 33,269.